# fabricjs - polygon update points on scaling

Tags: set, polygon, fabricjs, scaling, points

I'm trying to set points after polygon scaling.

But after :

```
var coords = this.getCoords( ... );

polygon.set({
    points: coords
});

polygon._calcDimensions();

polygon.scaleX = 1;
polygon.scaleY = 1;

polygon.zoomX = 1;
polygon.zoomY = 1;
```

Everything is fine except my polygon is offset.

- Example:
  [original on bottom & sclaled on top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPasW.png)
- console.dir : 
  [my fabric.Polygon object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rBBL.png)

Comment: Mind putting together a JSFiddle or Plunker?

Comment: is very unclear what are you trying to achieve.